# Overriding an adapter

Tags: java, android, adapter, overriding

I use an adapter to manipulate my listView , to have a nicer result i overrided the adapter. the problem is that when i use "setOnItemClickListener" to open another fragment with getting the content of the clicked item nothing happened!

```
ClientAdapter adapter = new ClientAdapter(
   getActivity(),R.layout.item_client, R.id.textV, clients);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3 {
      FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
      Client t = (Client) lv.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
      Modifier_Client fargmentACharger = new Modifier_Client();
      fargmentACharger.setClient(t);
      fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fargmentACharger).addToBackStack(null).commit();    
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a clear what the problem do you have

1. onItemClickListener don't work ?
2. You can't send data to another fragment ?

I don't see how you send data to another fragment, but you should use something like this:

```
 Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("client", t);
        fargmentACharger.setArguments(args);
```

or parselable the class Client

An get it at fragment

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    .....


        client = getArguments().getString("client");
}
```

Comment: i think that the problem is from  onItemClickListener because i tried the same code and it worked

Comment: It's easy to check, add logging and you can see this.  lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3 {  Log.d("My debug", "click happened");

Comment: in fact i tried with an ArrayAdapter (without the ClientAdapter) and it worked . so i think  the problem is caused by the new adapter that i've created : ClientAdapter.